How does the Android Studio transfer a folder to device?
When I use
adb shell "run-as com.example.myapplication push C:\\Users\\x00879271\\Desktop\\ttest /data/data/com.example.myapplication"
I get

run-as: exec failed for push: Permission denied.

And I can drag the 'ttest' folder to /data/data/com.example.myapplication using Android Studio.
So the question is:

How does the Android Studio transfer a folder to the device?
Or how should I transfer a folder to /data/data/com.example.myapplication without using root?


Let's take a close look onto the command you have executed:
adb shell "run-as com.example.myapplication push C:\\Users\\x00879271\\Desktop\\ttest /data/data/com.example.myapplication"
The main problem is the adb shell part at the beginning. With this command you open up a shell on the Android device. Everything after adb shell is executed on your Android device. Therefore specifying a path like C:\\Users\\x00879271\\Desktop\\ttest which refers to a file on your PC won't work because it is executed on Android which doesn't have access to files on your PC.
If you want to push a file and use run-as you can not do this in one command. Split it into multiple commands:

Push the file to a common directory: adb push C:\\Users\\x00879271\\Desktop\\ttest /sdcard/

Copy the file to into the app directory
adb shell run-as com.example.app sh -c 'cp /sdcard/ttest  /data/data/com.example.myapplication/'


The above command requires the cp command to be present on your device. On older devices it is missing which requires you to use a workaround using cat: 'cat /sdcard/ttest > /data/data/com.example.myapplication/ttest' for the last part of the command.
If you are interested what commands Android Studio performs when uploading an file e.g. in Device Explorer please see my answer here.
